# Get Absolute XPath of Web Element

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath

I'm using Javascript in the following code to retrieve the absolute `XPath` of a web element:

```
public String getAbsoluteXPath(WebDriver driver)
{
    return  (String) driver.executeScript(
            "function absoluteXPath(element) {"+
                    "var comp, comps = [];"+
                    "var parent = null;"+
                    "var xpath = '';"+
                    "var getPos = function(element) {"+
                    "var position = 1, curNode;"+
                    "if (element.nodeType == Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE) {"+
                    "return null;"+
                    "}"+
                    "for (curNode = element.previousSibling; curNode; curNode = curNode.previousSibling){"+
                    "if (curNode.nodeName == element.nodeName) {"+
                    "++position;"+
                    "}"+
                    "}"+
                    "return position;"+
                    "};"+

"if (element instanceof Document) {"+
"return '/';"+
"}"+

"for (; element && !(element instanceof Document); element = element.nodeType == Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE ? element.ownerElement : element.parentNode) {"+
"comp = comps[comps.length] = {};"+
"switch (element.nodeType) {"+
"case Node.TEXT_NODE:"+
"comp.name = 'text()';"+
"break;"+
"case Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE:"+
"comp.name = '@' + element.nodeName;"+
"break;"+
"case Node.PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE:"+
"comp.name = 'processing-instruction()';"+
"break;"+
"case Node.COMMENT_NODE:"+
"comp.name = 'comment()';"+
"break;"+
"case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:"+
"comp.name = element.nodeName;"+
"break;"+
"}"+
"comp.position = getPos(element);"+
"}"+

"for (var i = comps.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {"+
"comp = comps[i];"+
"xpath += '/' + comp.name.toLowerCase();"+
"if (comp.position !== null) {"+
"xpath += '[' + comp.position + ']';"+
"}"+
"}"+

"return xpath;"+

"} return absoluteXPath(arguments[0]);", this.element);

}
```

Generally, this produces the correct result. However, if I navigate to stackoverflow.com and attempt to retrieve the XPath of the element with the XPath ID of: `.//*[@id='hot-network-questions']/h4/a`   ("Hot Network Questions") the actual/expected XPath (according to `Firebug`) is: `html/body/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[3]/h4/a`  however this script incorrectly produces the value of: `/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[4]/h4[1]/a[1]`

Note the difference between div[3] and div[4] toward the end.

Comment: Either this is a really subtle bug in your script, or it's just a symptom of absolute `xpaths` being unreliable. Are your results different on the same loaded page? Or is it a different instance of the browser and navigation to the site that produces different results? If it's not the same instance, my guess is the page just rendered slightly differently your second time through.

Comment: Why do you need absolute xpath?

Comment: I tried to implement your code to find absolute XPath for based on relative XPath of web element provided, but I am getting issue like "Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined". Could you please help what I might be missing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On [current](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43003935/get-absolute-xpath-of-web-element) page your code returns following value to me when try to identify
[WebElement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kc4mv.jpg)

```
/html[1]/body[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div[6]/h4[1]/a[1]
```

Probably that is dependent on your session to the site and what sections are being displayed at that time; you can try seearching via xpath on the same session where you execute this code.